# Single Page App (SPA) utilizing several lists and libraries

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, spa

Does anyone else build SPAs with multiple lists and libraries? I've built many with single lists or libraries. My task is to build an app which would allow users to enter data about a project, upload documents related to the project, and add multiple daily updates for the project. My idea is to use 1 list for information about the project, 1 list for the daily updates, and 1 library for docs. The SPA allows users to select their project from a drop down and then display everything about the project on the page including buttons to add daily updates and upload documents.

I have implemented the example above as a proof of concept and it works as expected. I am passing the Project ID along with the document uploads and daily updates to use as a primary key for each Project.

My concern is that the actual proposed app contains many more components that will be broken out into separate lists like tasks for different departments. I'm already up to 6 AJAX calls and will need many more.

At what point would performance start to degrade?

Are there any tips or best practices from those who have created similar SPAs before?

Limitations: SP 2013 On-Prem, Front-End and CSOM only. Cannot use JS frameworks that require node. Currently using JavaScript, jQuery, MomentJS, Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality using OOTB connected web parts and list web parts.

I guess you are using the lookup from Projects list into the document library where you are uploading documents related to project.

So you can use this Project ID column as a common column to connect list and library using connected web parts.

[Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/04/25/creating-connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint/) you can find how to connect web parts in SharePoint.

Comment: Connected web parts gets about 25% of the job done and the interface is not very intuitive and leaves a lot to be desired. The app needs to be user friendly and remove pain points and inefficiencies. A use case to consider is that if a user tries to add a daily update, they will have to manually choose the project to which it belongs. This could introduce errors which could be avoided with considerate design.

My questions is not really concerning the method to accomplish the task but, best practices for using JavaScript and the REST API to manipulate multiple lists in a single page app.

Comment: If you are using multiple Ajax calls and want to improve performance then you should identify the calls independent to each other and use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) in jquery and for dependent calls use [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) in jquery.